# Displaying my getRank in my JTextField

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this method(see below). It's suppose to search through an input file which has been stored in array to find all the names for any that contain a matching substring (not case-sensitive) to what the user has enter as a name in the JTextField. This method does this. However, when it prints the name it's also suppose to print it's bestDecade (like 1920) with it. I have a...

```
public int getRank(int decade) {
    int decadeRank = rank[decade];
    return decadeRank;
}
```

which get's the decade year, so rank[0] represents 1900 and rank[1] represents 1910.

```
public int bestDecade() {
    int best = rank[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < DECADES; i++)
        if(rank[i] > best)
            best = rank[i];
    return best;
}
```

which gets the name's best rank number for a certain decade so like 351. However, I can't seem to figure out how to display the rank decade and not the rank number. You can see below, what I've been trying, but isn't working. So does anyone know how I can get the rank to display?

```
private void match(String targetSubstring)
{
    displayArea.setText("");
    displayArea.append("FIND RESULTS for: " + targetSubstring);
    displayArea.append("\n");
    displayArea.append("\n Name               Best Decade");
    displayArea.append("\n---------------         ---------------");
    targetSubstring = targetSubstring.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
        String theName = namesArray[i].getName();
        if (theName.toUpperCase().contains(targetSubstring))
        {
            int best = namesArray[i].bestDecade(); //this is what I've been trying
            displayArea.append("\n" + namesArray[i].getName() + (namesArray[i].getRank(best)));
            //  displayArea.append(best);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking this as the main issue :

> I can't seem to figure out how to display the rank decade and not the rank number

And with this information

> rank[0] represents 1900 and rank[1] represents 1910

And knowing that your function returns the numbers 190, 1910 etc. Since you return `rank[best]` but you later use the return value `getRank(best)`, you should return `i`, or erase the `getRank` function and use the returned value.

*Assuming the rest of your code works*

**Option 1:**

```
// Your code, no changes
public int bestDecade() {
    int best = rank[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < DECADES; i++)
        if(rank[i] > best)
            best = rank[i];
    return best; // Returns 1900, 1910 etc..
}

// Changes here to show the returned value (1900, 1910 etc.) directly
int best = namesArray[i].bestDecade(); //this is what I've been trying
displayArea.append("\n" + namesArray[i].getName() + best);
```

**Option 2:**

```
// Changes here to return "i" 
public int bestDecade() {
    int best = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < DECADES; i++)
        if(rank[i] > rank[best])
            best = i;
    return best; // Returns values between [0 .. DECADES)
}

// No changes here, use returned value, [0 .. DECADES) in 
int best = namesArray[i].bestDecade(); // You have "i" here, the index of rank
displayArea.append("\n" + namesArray[i].getName() + namesArray[i].getRank(best)); // Use "i" here, rank[i]
```